# How do I take a number input, change it, then out put it, with submit button?

Tags: java, android, button

I am completely lost and don't have enough knowledge on coding/android studio.

I have the EditTexts (FoodIncomeCounter, FoodCampX, and FoodUpgradeX) as inputs.

Then the TextView (FoodIncomeResult) as output.

The 1st button (IncomeSubmitButton) Works properly. The 2nd button (FoodCampSubmitButton) does not, I want it to take the input of the FoodCampXs and FoodUpgradeXs then do a calculation and put that into integer TotalFood, then output TotalFood to the FoodIncomeResult TextView.

How the heck do I do this? I feel like I am close but I don't know what is wrong.
Thank you for the help!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// These are the global variables
EditText FoodIncomeCounter;
EditText FoodCamp1Counter, FoodCamp2Counter, FoodCamp3Counter, FoodUpgrade1Counter, FoodUpgrade2Counter, FoodUpgrade3Counter;
TextView FoodIncomeResult;
int FoodIncome;
int FoodCamp1, FoodCamp2, FoodCamp3, FoodUpgrade1, FoodUpgrade2, FoodUpgrade3;
int TotalFood;
Button IncomeSubmitButton, FoodCampSubmitButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //to get from user input and into variable form

    FoodIncomeCounter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodIncomeCounter);
    FoodIncomeResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FoodIncomeResult);
    IncomeSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IncomeSubmitButton);

    FoodCamp1Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodCamp1Counter);
    FoodCamp2Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodCamp2Counter);
    FoodCamp3Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodCamp3Counter);
    FoodUpgrade1Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodUpgrade1Counter);
    FoodUpgrade2Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodUpgrade2Counter);
    FoodUpgrade3Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodUpgrade3Counter);
    FoodCampSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FoodCampSubmitButton);


    //Submit button
    IncomeSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //to receive the inputted values

            Food = Integer.parseInt(FoodIncomeCounter.getText().toString());

            //to show the inputted values into the result fields

            FoodIncomeResult.setText(FoodIncomeCounter.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    //Submit button
    FoodCampSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //receive the inputted values
            FoodCamp1 = Integer.parseInt(FoodCamp1Counter.getText().toString());
            FoodCamp2 = Integer.parseInt(FoodCamp2Counter.getText().toString());
            FoodCamp3 = Integer.parseInt(FoodCamp3Counter.getText().toString());
            FoodUpgrade1 = Integer.parseInt(FoodUpgrade1Counter.getText().toString());
            FoodUpgrade2 = Integer.parseInt(FoodUpgrade2Counter.getText().toString());
            FoodUpgrade3 = Integer.parseInt(FoodUpgrade3Counter.getText().toString());

            //get food income and show
            TotalFood = FoodCamp1 + (FoodCamp2 * 2) + (FoodCamp3 * 3) + (FoodUpgrade1 * 2) + (FoodUpgrade2 * 4) + (FoodUpgrade3 * 6);
            FoodIncomeResult.setText(String.valueOf(TotalFood));
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: "It doesn't work", is not a good enough problem description. There's only one way the code works, there's nearly infinity of ways it doesn't.

Comment: How do I take an integer (TotalFood), turn it into a string and that value output into FoodIncomeResult? FoodIncomeResult.setText(String.valueOf(TotalFood)); does not do what I am trying to do. I want it to change the value of FoodIncomeResult when the FoodCampSubmitButton is pressed. How do I do that with what I have?

Comment: You already change text of `FoodIncomeResult` when `FoodCampSubmitButton` is pressed, according to the code. If something doesn't work still, you will have to dig deeper into this to understand what doesn't work.